# Why doesn't controller's name has "controller" in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the route config, you will have
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

Here controller = "Home" instead of the defined public class HomeController : Controller. 
Does the compiler automatically append "Controller" at the end of Home?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is answered in-depth here:

[Why do MVC controllers have to have the trailing 'Controller' convention on their class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11557194/3437962)

The short answer is that ASP.NET MVC employs the controller naming convention for standardization purposes. The compiler won't recognize a controller class unless it has a "Name" + "Controller" structure.

In contrast, when referencing a controller you can leave off the "Controller" and just call the name. It's apart of MVC framework.